# How to isolate a single element from a scraped web page in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rcurl

I want to use R to scrape this page: (http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/germany2006/results/matches/match=97410001/report.html ) and others, to get the goal scorers and times.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)

theURL <-"http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/germany2006/results/matches/match=97410001/report.html"
webpage <- getURL(theURL, header=FALSE, verbose=TRUE) 
webpagecont <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)  

pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpagecont, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

and the pagetree object now contains a pointer to my parsed html (I think).  The part I want is:

```
<div class="cont")<ul>
<div class="bold medium">Goals scored</div>
        <li>Philipp LAHM (GER) 6', </li>
        <li>Paulo WANCHOPE (CRC) 12', </li>
        <li>Miroslav KLOSE (GER) 17', </li>
        <li>Miroslav KLOSE (GER) 61', </li>
        <li>Paulo WANCHOPE (CRC) 73', </li>
        <li>Torsten FRINGS (GER) 87'</li>
</ul></div>
```

But I'm now lost as to how to isolate them, and frankly `xpathSApply` and `xpathApply` confuse the beejeebies out of me!

So, does anyone know how to formulate a command to suck out the element contained within the `<div class="cont">` tags?

Comment: Be careful when doing stuff like this... In most cases, organizations like FIFA or FIBA, NBA etc. don't allow utilization of their data - simply stated: their data is their property! So next time provide some dummy HTML code, or just point to some harmless site! =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These questions are very helpful when dealing with web scraping and XML in R:

1. [Scraping html tables into R data frames using the XML package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package)
2. [How to transform XML data into a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067098/how-to-transform-xml-data-into-a-data-frame)

With regards to your particular example, while I'm not sure what you want the output to look like, this gets the "goals scored" as a character vector:

```
theURL <-"http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/germany2006/results/matches/match=97410001/report.html"
fifa.doc <- htmlParse(theURL)
fifa <- xpathSApply(fifa.doc, "//*/div[@class='cont']", xmlValue)
goals.scored <- grep("Goals scored", fifa, value=TRUE)
```

The `xpathSApply` function gets all the values that match the given criteria, and returns them as a vector.  Note how I'm looking for a div with class='cont'.  Using class values is frequently a good way to parse an HTML document because they are good markers.

You can clean this up however you want:

```
> gsub("Goals scored", "", strsplit(goals.scored, ", ")[[1]])
[1] "Philipp LAHM (GER) 6'"    "Paulo WANCHOPE (CRC) 12'" "Miroslav KLOSE (GER) 17'" "Miroslav KLOSE (GER) 61'" "Paulo WANCHOPE (CRC) 73'"
[6] "Torsten FRINGS (GER) 87'"
```

Comment: Pretty neat, I was looking for something like this long time ago, but ended up in Python! Now I can run littler script and populate dataset! Cool!