# How to scrape "table like" data from stackexchange homepage? (in R)

Tags: r, web-scraping

I wish to scrape the home page of one of the new stackexchange websites: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  (just once, and for only several pages, nothing that should bother the servers).  If I had wanted it from stackoverflow, I know there is a database dump, but for the new stackexchange, they don't exist yet.

Here is what I want to do.

Step 1: choose URL

```
URL <- "https://webapps.stackexchange.com/"
```

Step 2: read the table

```
readHTMLTable(URL)  # oops, doesn't work - gives NULL
```

Step 2: this time, let's try it with XML

```
htmlTreeParse(URL) # o.k, this reads the data - but it is all in <div> - now what?
```

So I was able to read the page, but now the structure is in divs.  How can it now be used to create the same thing as readHTMLTable ?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395528/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames-using-the-xml-package

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998655/how-to-isolate-a-single-element-from-a-scraped-web-page-in-r/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with [the `overflowr` package](http://code.google.com/p/overflowr/) (with the StackExchange API).  Just use the get.questions() function and supply the site prefix.  It's not on CRAN since it isn't complete, but you can download it and build it.

```
library(overflowr)
questions <- get.questions(50)
```

For the statistics site, the top 5 most recent questions:

```
questions <- get.questions(top.n=5, site="stats.stackexchange")
```

Incidentally, happy to include more people working on this project because I don't have any more time to spend on it.  [Three of the moderators from Stats.Exchange are currently working on it](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/r-stackexchange-package).

Comment: This looks great Shane!!  Any chance that there is a download link of version for windows that was already built?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  You will have to check it out from svn and build it.  I don't see much point in providing a download version until there's more to it.  The core infrastructure is there, but you can't do basic things (like pull answers).

Comment: Great, and if you make an enhancements, please feel free to submit them back.

Answer (score 0):

What are you writing this in? I wrote an application that parses out of a web scrape ([link](http://codebase.joshuakehn.com/homestead/)). I would be more then happy to share the logic.