# How to remove or re-tag self-closing XML tags when coercing XML code to a data frame with R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to convert some XML code into an R data frame using [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067098/how-to-transform-xml-data-into-a-data-frame).  Unfortunately, self-closing tags appear to be preventing this conversion and my understanding of XML (and the R XML package) is novice at best.

According to [this page at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), it looks like self-closing tags are legal in XML, so the code I'm attempting to parse through isn't terribly out of whack.

The R code below will create the problem I'm experiencing.  If you remove the `<AlternateText/>` tag, the code works as I expect it to.

Also, oddly enough, if you change it to `<AlternateText xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>`, then it also works.  Is that behavior expected?

I would like to either simply remove all self-closing tags from the object `x` or I would like to re-tag them so they don't cause an error -- effectively changing `<AlternateText/>` into something like `<AlternateText></AlternateText>`.

```
x <- 
    '<outer>
        <ProviderURL>
          <URLCode>Valid</URLCode>
          <URLAddress>http://mypage.com</URLAddress>
          <AlternateText/>
        </ProviderURL>
    </outer>'

library( plyr )
library( XML )


y <- 
    xmlTreeParse( 
        x , 
        asText = TRUE , 
        useInternalNodes = TRUE
    )

ldply( xmlToList( y ) , data.frame )
```

This block of code gives me:

```
Error in data.frame(URLCode = "Valid", URLAddress = "http://mypage.com",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Comment: I dont think the example you posted agrees with what you are describing.  What output are you expecting from `<AlternateText/>` ?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta see edit.. do you get something different when you run that block of code?

Comment: The error has to do with haveing a lists of lists. Not with the xml tag.   ie, run this: `aL <- list(list(1:3, 1:2), 1:2);  
ldply(aL, data.frame)`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta i understand that's where it ultimately breaks, but the problem is rooted in the self-closing tag - and if i can eliminate them, it will be solved? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @RicardoSaporta in his last Edit the problem is because you have a NULL for one of your list elements. As an alternative yo get a data.frame you can use `unlist`

```
 unlist(xmlToList( y ))
   ProviderURL.URLCode ProviderURL.URLAddress 
               "Valid"    "http://mypage.com"
```

or using `xmlToDataFrame`

```
xmlToDataFrame(y)


  URLCode        URLAddress AlternateText
1   Valid http://mypage.com
```

*PS*

Note that `xmlTreeParse` with `useInternalNodes = TRUE` can be replaced by a simple `xmlParse`

```
y <- 
    xmlParse( 
        x , 
        asText = TRUE  
    )
```

Comment: this gives me `Opening and ending tag mismatch: ProviderURL line 2 and outer
Premature end of data in tag outer line 1
Error: 1: Opening and ending tag mismatch: ProviderURL line 2 and outer
2: Premature end of data in tag outer line 1`

Comment: when i copy and paste your code into R, i get that error at the `xmlParse` line..  (and it's not just the stray comma)

Answer (score 0):

When you pare the xml, using the code from your example, the tag you are looking for is right there. I dont think that is what is giving you the issue

```
y <- xmlTreeParse(x, asText=TRUE, useInternalNodes=TRUE)

xmlToList(y)

# $ProviderURL
# $ProviderURL$URLCode
# [1] "Valid"

# $ProviderURL$URLAddress
# [1] "http://mypage.com"

# $ProviderURL$AlternateText  
# NULL    <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ It's Right There
```

---

#### This should help:

```
y.list <- xmlToList(y)
y.list$ProviderURL$AlternateText <- NA
ldply(y.list, data.frame)
```

---

The issue is *not* the self-closing tag.  The issue is that you have a list with a NULL value and that is messing with ldply.  Normally lists do not have NULL values (ie, assigning NULL often eliminates the value from the list).

Therefore, if you instead assign an alternate value, ldply will be fine. Alternatively, if you assign it NULL, it will drop from your list.

Comment: thanks for the edit ..but i need to remove them systematically.  hardcoding the `<- NA` won't solve my problem :(