# parsing XML to R when multiple nodes with the same names

Tags: r, xml

I have a XML file with nodes having the same name and I can't find out how to select the data I want in order to create a dataframe. I'm new to R and XML and I can't seem to make it work!

My XML looks like this (only the beginning):

```
<GL_Document xmlns="">
    <time_Period.timeInterval>...</time_Period.timeInterval>
    <TimeSeries>
        <mRID>1</mRID>
        <MktPSRType>
            <psrType>ProdType1</psrType>
        </MktPSRType>
        <Period>
            <timeInterval>
                <start>2015-12</start>
                <end>2016-11</end>
            </timeInterval>
            <resolution>PT60M</resolution>
            <Point>
                <position>1</position>
                <quantity>9</quantity>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <position>2</position>
                <quantity>7</quantity>
            </Point>
            <Point>
                <position>3</position>
                <quantity>9</quantity>
            </Point>
```

The code contains different nodes named "TimeSeries" with the same type of data (here Period is not developed in order to see the whole structure)

```
<GL_Document xmlns="">
    <time_Period.timeInterval>...</time_Period.timeInterval>
    <TimeSeries>
        <mRID>1</mRID>
        <MktPSRType>
            <psrType>ProdType1</psrType>
        </MktPSRType>
        <Period>...</Period>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>
        <mRID>2</mRID>
        <MktPSRType>
            <psrType>ProdType2</psrType>
        </MktPSRType>
        <Period>...</Period>
    </TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>...</TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>...</TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>...</TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>...</TimeSeries>
    <TimeSeries>...</TimeSeries>
</GL_Document>
```

I want to get the data in the following format:

```
psrType    position   quantity  
ProdType1   1         9
...        ...        ...
ProdType2   1         ...
```

I have tried to apply the solutions as mentioned in this post: [How to parse XML to R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198658/how-to-parse-xml-to-r-data-frame)
But unsuccessfully. 
My code looks like this, but I the resulting dataframe contains no data:

```
xml.url3<-getURL(xml.file3)
doc<-xmlParse(xml.url3)

position_path<-"//GL_Document/TimeSeries/Period/Point/position"
quantity_path<-"//GL_Document/TimerSeries/Period/Point/quantity"

df<-data.frame(
  pos=as.integer(sapply(doc[position_path],as,"integer")),
  quant=as.integer(sapply(doc[quantity_path],as,"integer")))
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ok, so finally this is what I did:
` xml.fileexp<-"https://website.com"
 xml.urlexp<-getURL(xml.fileexp)
doc<-xmlParse(xml.urlexp)
df <- ldply(xmlToList(doc), data.frame)
dfexp<-df[df$.id=="TimeSeries",]`

Comment: Ok sorry, I have to comment twice.. not time left for editing! Then I had a dataframe with every thing inside my timeseries nodes listed (in rows). As starting and stoping time were given, I could write a code taking into account the number of positions in the interval.. Probably not the most clever solutionm but it works!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using XML's `xpathSApply()` to run direct XPath expressions. For the *psrType* value, use `ancestor::*` which `data.frame()` maps the one value per `<TimeSeries>` to each corresponding values of *period* and *quantity*:

```
library(XML)

xml.url3 <- getURL(xml.file3)
doc <- xmlParse(xml.url3)

period <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Point/position", xmlValue)
quantity <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Point/quantity", xmlValue)
psrType <- xpathSApply(doc, "//Point/ancestor::TimeSeries/MktPSRType/psrType", xmlValue)

df <- data.frame(psrType = psrType,
                 period = as.integer(period),
                 quantity = as.integer(quantity))

df
#     psrType period quantity
# 1 ProdType2      1        9
# 2 ProdType2      2        7
# 3 ProdType2      3        9
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find what you need here:
[How to transform XML data into a data.frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067098/how-to-transform-xml-data-into-a-data-frame)

This `xmlToList()` looks about right. You can then get it into a data framee by using one of the apply methods. There is a grea explanation at the above link!